# Texas BQ25756 battery charger

Tags: battery-charging

I am considering using the TI  [BQ25756](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25756.pdf) battery charger in my new design.

I wonder if the input power to the charger will be effective in powering my device even when the battery will not be populated.

Comment: don't you mean `output from` the charger? ... also, the manufacturer  is Texas Instruments, the name is not just Texas  as stated in the title

Comment: Yes, I meant 'output from the charger'. Regarding the manufacturer name, it is indeed Texas Instruments - I used a nickname/

Comment: please correct your post... it still says *input to the charger*

Comment: No need to correct - In this case the input and output are actually synonyms when the battery is not populated. I already got good answer from Robin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work provided you configure it for autonomous operation correctly (meaning you need to get the ILIM, FB, FSW_SYNC and TS resistor networks to be conservative).   Then when VAC goes into the ACUV..ACOV range the H-bridge will start pumping current towards the system and battery.
In your scenario the battery isn't there, but you will have some capacitance (Csys + 80uF in their example).  Assuming your system uses some current, it will be indistinguishable from the battery being nearly full.

The system will regulate SYSTEM to whatever voltage is programmed by the resistor divider feeding the FB pin.

If you plan on having the battery removable you need to consider TS also - when the NTC in the battery pack is missing, the two resistors across TS will set a voltage - is that voltage going to indicate that the battery temperature is OK for charging?  If not, then I suspect the chip won't start pumping.   So you may need to do something a bit clever here.

Also the I2C registers will cold start in this configuration so you have to look at all of them and decide whether their default settings are compatible with your target configuration.   Obviously you might have a microcontroller powered by SYSTEM and that can quickly reprogram the I2C registers.

If it turns out you cannot use the defaults then you might need to have the micro powered from the line side, have CE strapped to inactive by default, then have the micro use GPIOs and I2C to get the BQ into a good state *before* you then let it start pumping current.

Comment: Thank you very much Robin for your detailed answer. I am going indeed to use the default and nominal configuration. Also the NTC remark is useful.